# How to set the body on an apache camel http POST request

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-camel

I am simply trying to send credentials to a restful service that takes in a json formatted username and password and will return an access token. No matter what I try, I get a 400 error and the error returned from the server is "Must supply a body." Here's the last snippet I tried:

```
@Component
public class LoginRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

String jsonCredentials =  "{\"username\":\"username\",\"password\":\"password\",\"grant_type\":\"password\",\"scope\":\"admin\"}";

from("timer://login?repeatCount=1")
    .setBody(constant(jsonCredentials))
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpMethods.POST))
    .to("http://URL");
  }
}
```

I have confirmed my credentials work fine in Postman and receive the proper response, with access token. I believe the service I am trying to connect to is using Oauth2.

Comment: did you try to set the content-type header?: .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"));

Answer (score 0):

Try marshalling. For me this worked:

```
// your custom defined bean
Credentials creds = new Credentials(username, password, ...);
from(...).setBody(creds).marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson).to(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using Spring XML

```
    <route>
      <from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
      <setHeader name="CamelHttpMethod">
        <constant>POST</constant>
      </setHeader>
      <setHeader name="Content-Type">
        <constant>application/json</constant>
      </setHeader>
      <setBody>
        <constant>{ "params": { "login": "my_username", "password": "my_password" } }</constant>
      </setBody>
      <to uri="https://myapi.com/login" />
      <to uri="log:info?showBody=true&amp;showHeaders=true" />
    </route>
```